# Is my SSD Object Detection output correct?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, solid-state-drive

I am using tflite in a unique way; building an [Object Detection as a Service](https://github.com/second-state/wasm-learning/tree/master/faas/ssd_mobilenet).

Cut a long story short, I get the following output when I perform the TFLite Object Detection on a single image

```
[0.018407762, 0.022299409, 0.9639402, 0.98289526, 0.77566934, 0.95224416, 0.7893053, 0.9644519, 0.079119, 0.25176272, 0.8338728, 0.9715638, 0.7666425, 0.9561646, 0.7853481, 0.968181, 0.7755212, 0.9020464, 0.7879235, 0.91752034, 0.5012923, 0.009573311, 0.9884741, 1.0051035, 0.7762802, 0.3704026, 0.7917542, 0.38168278, 0.7762862, 0.4714918, 0.7886885, 0.4809718, 0.7762862, 0.2167234, 0.7886885, 0.22408514, 0.778196, 0.5809637, 0.78983843, 0.59090406]

[4.0, 37.0, 4.0, 37.0, 37.0, 4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 15.0]

[0.37890625, 0.30078125, 0.21484375, 0.20703125, 0.19921875, 0.19140625, 0.18359375, 0.17578125, 0.16796875, 0.16796875]

[10.0]
```

The model data I am using is simply the `detect.tflite` file which was extracted from the ["Starter model with metadata"](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview)

If I process a picture of a bicycle I get 10 different object ids back i.e. `[4.0, 37.0, 4.0, 37.0, 37.0, 4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 15.0]` which is not correct.

Also whilst I have transformed the original [labelmap.txt file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/second-state/wasm-learning/master/faas/ssd_mobilenet/src/labelmap.txt)into [this new format](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/second-state/wasm-learning/master/faas/ssd_mobilenet/src/labelmap_v2.txt) as suggested in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tensorflow-lite-for-object-detection-2a0283f94aed) I am still not sure how the labelmap is supposed to be incorporated/used in this object detection process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems that the values in the first part of the output which allow us to draw the rectangle bounding boxes (the 40 values which make up 4 values per each of the 10 detections) are too small. Not sure why they would be less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

The outputs are well documented here: [How to resolve tensorflow shape issue when using a custom model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402482/how-to-resolve-tensorflow-shape-issue-when-using-a-custom-model)

The id of the class is in `TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1`. you can map id in this output with that in your labelmap.txt